# How can I get these loops to work? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, while-loop

```js
function CountDown() {
  var i;
  var power = 100;
  for (i = 0; i > (power - 10); i--) {
    document.write("<p>Po's Power:</p>" + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function whileDown() {
  var i;
  var p = 100;
  while (i => 100; i--) {
    document.write("<p>Po's Power:</p>" + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function CountUp() {
  var i;
  var p = 0;
  for (i = 100; i >= (p + 10); i++) {
    p += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("power").innerHTML = p
}

function whileUp() {
  var i;
  var p = 0;
  while (i = < 100)(
    document.write("<p>Po's Power:</p>" + i + "<br>")
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="power"></p>
<header>
  <h1>Kung Fu Panda Count Down/Count Up</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Click on the buttons below to do Po's power level count down / count up.</h2>
  <p><input type="button" id="power" value=" Po count down 1 using FOR loop" onclick="CountDown();" /></p>
  <p><input type="button" id="power" value=" Po count down 1 using While loop" onclick="whileDown();" /></p>
  <p><input type="button" id="power" value="Po count up 1 using FOR loop" onclick="CountUp();" /></p>
  <p><input type="button" id="power" value=" Po count up 1 using While loop" onclick="WhileUp();" /></p>
</main>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm doing this for class so I'm not used to doing something like this. I have to count down for the first two loops and count up on the last two. I have tried to get the buttons to work as well and I get them to work but not in the way I would like them to work. I have also gotten the one for loop to work but it doesn't count into increments of 10 which is another requirement for this class.

Comment: I have to Count down from 100 the first two loops and count up to 100 one the second two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop does not work:

```
var power=100;
for ( i=0; i> (power-10); i--){
```

It means loop works while i > (power - 10) and in the second round when i is -1, it is not larger than (power -10), then loop will end.

If you want it works 10 round:

```
for ( i = power; i> (power-10); i--){
```

Comment: How do I get it to decrease by 10 then?

Comment: Which one? The first one or second?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can see this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: For the first one, it has to decrease by 10 each time.

Comment: Please see the answer, I added that. `for ( i = power; i> (power-10); i--){`

Comment: @FarzinKanzi the 1st loop is not infinite (will not even run a single iteration), as 0 is not greater than 90
and the 3rd one fails after the first iteration because p becomes `0The number is 100<br>`, which is not comparable to the integer 101